# Show text in large type on the screen via terminal

Tags: terminal

I can put large text on the center of my screen with certain apps, such as Address Book (click on a phone number and choose "Show in Large Type") or using Quicksilver (type some text and choose the "Large Type" action).

Is there any way I can invoke this functionality from the terminal, to show arbitrary large text by writing, say, Applescript or a bash script?

Comment: This is an insanely good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already have [QuickSilver](http://qsapp.com/) installed:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Quicksilver" to show large type "your text here"'
```

You can use this to define a bash function (and put somewhere like `~/.profile`):

```
function big {
        osascript -e "tell application \"Quicksilver\" to show large type \"$1\""
}
```

Then you can invoke it with arbitrary strings by doing

```
$ big "This will cause large text to appear"
```

Comment: That works, but can it be done without Quicksilver?

Comment: [growl](http://growl.info/) supports text overlay from the command line - and it's fairly customizable even though most of the presets are for small - side of the screen display of text. I'd go with QuickSilver, though as it's easier to get exactly the format you ask.